I have Least Significant Difference (LSD) value with me. I want to assign alphabets to sample means considering LSD value in R. How to do that?
I have 260 treatment means and I also have Least significant difference (LSD) value with me. I want to group these treatments using alphabets based on significant and non significant difference between treatments considering LSD value. Can you please help me by giving R codes for the same.
Agriculture_Data$Yield groups
# B                1.47125      a
# A                1.46375      a
# D                1.33875      a
# C                1.06750      b 
LSD value 0.25
I want to group as mentioned in the above example.

